# Do "coterminous" and "conterminous" have exactly the same meaning?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I am under the impression that both *coterminous* and *conterminous* have exactly the same meaning. There was a remark that Latin purists prefer *conterminous*. Why?

Is there any significant difference between the two? Do *co-* and *con-* have same effect on words?

I am looking for any additional information about these two words which would help me understand them better.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, *conterminous* and *coterminous* both mean "to share a boundary".

According to the entries for *co-* and *con-*, below, *co-* is an Anglicising of *con-*, which is possibly why Latin purists prefer *con-*

In this instance *co-* and *con-* both mean *together* or *with*.

[Etymology of co-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=co-)

> in Latin, the form of com- in compounds with stems beginning in vowels and h- and gn- (see com-). Taken in English from 17c. as a living prefix meaning “together, mutually, in common,” and used promiscuously with native words and Latin-derived words not beginning with vowels, sometimes even with words already having it (e.g. co-conspiritor).

[Etymology of con-](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=con-)

> prefix meaning "together, with," sometimes merely intensive; the form of com- used in Latin before consonants except -b-, -p-, -l-, -m-, or -r-. In native English formations, co- tends to be used where Latin would use con- (e.g. costar).

Comment: So the semantic fields of these words are coterminous.

Comment: "Sharing a boundary" is ambiguous as used in common English.  Does it mean to share a boundary as in two states sharing a river as a boundary, i.e., a partial bounds?  Or does it mean to share the entire boundary?  The latter excludes California and Nevada in the US sharing a boundary, while the former does not.  _In fact, this is what co- vs con-terminous seem to differentiate._

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary.com disagrees with the currently accepted answer. It lists "coterminous" as one of the possible meanings of "conterminous", but also two other meanings.

Its definitions of "coterminous":

1. having the same border or covering the same area.
2. being the same in extent; coextensive in range or scope.

Its definitions of "conterminous":

1. having a common boundary; bordering; contiguous.
2. meeting at the ends; without an intervening gap:
   *In our calendar system, the close of one year is conterminous with the beginning of the next.*
3. coterminous.

Indeed, the National Geographic Style Guide [says](http://web.archive.org/web/20160102075245/http://stylemanual.ngs.org/home/C/conterminous-contiguous-continental) to use "conterminous" for the 48 contiguous states of the U.S.; that fits with definition 1 for "conterminous" and not with either of the definitions for "coterminous".

Comment: I tend to agree with you/dictionary.com.  I am still confused, though.  Are Montana and North Dakota co/conterminous because they share the 49th parallel with Canada?  Or are they co/conterminous with each other, because they meet at their respective east/west ends?  Is DE co/conterminous with NJ because they share a border via Delaware River, and that they share PA as a border, but in either case each do not touch the other?  There seems to be times where Co- and Con- are synonymous, but are there times where one can be co- but not con-, or vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

"Con-" has the meaning of :

> used with certain words to add a notion similar to those conveyed by with, together, or joint
>   congenial, congregation, console, consonant, construct, converge, etc.

It has the same meaning as "co-", which means:

> together; mutually; jointly

["Conterminous"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conterminous) and ["Coterminous"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/coterminous) do mean the same.