# Coterminous vs. Conterminous?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context

Which word is more appropriate in a geographical mapping context when referring to counties in a state, contiguous states within a country, contiguous countries within a continent, etc?

Are they interchangeable? Based on this [n-gram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conterminous%2C%20coterminous&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconterminous%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccoterminous%3B%2Cc0) 'coterminous' is more common, though 'conterminous' seems more accurate?

Coterminous

- having the same border or covering the same area
- being the same in extent; coextensive in range or scope

Conterminous

- having a common boundary; bordering; contiguous
- meeting at the ends; without an intervening gap

Comment: [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/38645/3559) might be relevant to your interests.

Comment: Your Ngram link is odd: given that the two words mean different things, what does it matter which one is more common?

Comment: If they are synonymous or interchangeable, then I'd prefer the more commonly used word. If they aren't, then I agree that the n-gram doesn't offer any useful information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do "coterminous" and "conterminous" have exactly the same meaning?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38645/do-coterminous-and-conterminous-have-exactly-the-same-meaning)

Comment: **coterminous  Origin**  Late 18th century: alteration of conterminous. (ODO) https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/coterminous -- enough said.

Comment: @ruakh "given that the two words mean different things"?

Comment: Could you explain how or why this matters, please? 

In one or two contexts that you chose not to name, it might be vital.

Otherwise, why would anyone care, please?

Comment: What's wrong with "contiguous" or "overlapping" (whichever fits).  Not 1% of the population knows what "coterminous" and "conterminous" (supposedly) mean.

Answer (score 1):

The set of all counties would be coterminous with the state as a whole, occupying the same area.

One county would be conterminous with a neighboring county, having a common border.

Answer (score 0):

Good question. TBH, I'm not sure why, in both cases, it isn't in [latin declension](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Latin_second_declension)? (just "us" not "ous" -- greek?)

> **Edit - leaving parenthetical up. upon reflection, i think -us still noun, -ous, latin not greek, more at adjective. hence ous (edited below).

*Termin* - at end, final, limit (airport **termin**al, ex**termin**ate)

*co* - together, with, group (**co**ordinate, **co**evolve)

*con* - with (more at synchronized; **con**temporary, **con**(n)ect, **con**vey)

*coterminous* - ending at the same time (independent)

> The procedures are coterminus

*conterminous* - just seems wrong (maybe thats why it's used less). ending together (at mutual)

> **Edit (pt2) - con + terminus (con, think: Spanish). With ending (contra: cliffhanger). "The plot is conterminous" - but this is wrong, i think heh?*

As per your question - why doesn't contiguous work? If you mean "all the states of the union," why not constituent?

[And then there's the n-gram graph, from your source](https://kek.gg/i/54bT62.png)

Comment: I've never come across "conterminous"; my preference would be for "coterminous"; but I note that the Online Etymological Dictionary mentions that "coterminous" or "co-terminous" are "malformed in English" from Latin roots, and that "Latin purists prefer *conterminous*."

Comment: example: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0034425709002545 Now I'm wondering if one is used more often in an academic context. Here I believe it's referring to the lower 48 states.

Comment: @tautophile Latin purists remain mute spectators as writers prefer to save a letter. See the nGram!

Comment: @Kris yes I thought more about it over the weekend and have updated my answer...